# How to get id from li element?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to take the value of the.live() li element using jquery as the following code :

```
$("body").on("click", "#nav li:has(ul)", function (event) {
   if (this == event.target) {
      $(this).toggleClass('clicked').children('ul').slideToggle();
      $(this).find('li:has(ul)').removeClass('clicked').find("ul").slideUp();
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('clicked').find("ul").slideUp();
   }
})

$("#content").load("content.html");
```

and inside `content.html` I put some code like this:

```
   <ul id="nav">
       <li value='2012'>2012
         <ul>
             <li value='Geography'>Geography</li>
             <li value='Topography'>Topography</li>
             <li value='Geological'>Geological</li>
             <li value='Seismology'>Seismology</li>
             <li value='Volcanology'>Volcanology</li>
             <li value='Oceanography'>Oceanography</li>
             <li value='Hydrogeology'>Hydrogeology</li>
             <li value='Meteorology'>Meteorology</li>
             <li value='Demography'>Demography</li>
         </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>
```

So, when I click in the li element, `alert($('li').attr('value')`,
how to get its value?

Comment: Not an answer just an improvement. Instead of doing `$(this)` multiple times it is better to do `var elem = $(this);` and use `elem` multiple times.

Comment: The `value` attribute in `li` elements is deprecated.

Comment: I wasn't aware that `.on`, `.one`, and `.off` had deprecated `.live`, `.bind`, and `.delegate`.  You've shaken my world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your event listener, add an extra `else` condition to the event listener.

Unless prevented, the event will always fire on click on (the descendants of) the `#nav li:has(ul)` element. Check whether the `event.target` element points to a `<li>`.

```
$("body").on("click", "#nav li:has(ul)", function (event) {
   var $target = $(event.target);
   if (this == event.target) {
      $target.toggleClass('clicked').children('ul').slideToggle()
      $target.find('li:has(ul)').removeClass('clicked').find("ul").slideUp()
      $target.siblings().removeClass('clicked').find("ul").slideUp();
   } else if ($.nodeName(event.target, 'li')) {
       // LI element, not the root li
       var val = $target.attr('value');
   }
});
```

This code assumes that the clicked `<li>` element does not have any other descendants (that is: plain-text). If it does, you have to traverse the tree as well.

Instead of adding a non-standard `value` attribute, I recommend to use `data`-attributes, eg:

```
<li data-value='Geological'>Geological</li>
```

Getting the value of the data-attribute:

```
$target.attr('data-value'); // Or:
$target.data('value');
```

Comment: i've tried your code, but it return error... retruning value is `0`

Comment: @JinSun jQuery seems to fail on the `value` attribute. Replacing `value` with `data-value` solves the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/SGGuf/

Comment: it works, but duplicated value... when i click `2012` it is ok. but when i click `Geography` it appear two `GeographyGeography` and so on

Comment: My fiddle works correctly. I guess that you're using `$("selector")` instead of a cached `$target`. That selects all elements which matches the selector. `.attr("data-value")` returns a concatenated string of all `data-value` attributes.

Comment: @JinSun 8 seconds before you posted that comment, I've already replies.

Comment: @JinSun Add `event.stopPropagation()` at the top of your event listener. Your selector matches multiple nested elements, hence the multiple alerts. [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) stops the event bubble after firing one event.

Comment: i dont understand, how to implement it?

Comment: @JinSun Exactely as I said: Put `event.stopPropagation();` right after `$("body").on("click", "#nav li:has(ul)", function (event) {`.

Comment: sorry, dealying reply.. i've tried this code, and it is works! thankyou my bro... and i dont understand what is `stopPropagation()` mean?

Comment: @JinSun Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). In plain english: Usually, when an event is triggered, the event is fired for each element in the element's tree, from the original element to the top (`document`) ("event bubble"). After calling [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), the bubble stops. In other words, the event is not fired for the parents any more.

Comment: how about call li element parents ? when i click li paren then appear li children, it show data-value from li parent until last li children i've clicked...

Comment: @JinSun `.find()` searches for all descendants. Use `.children()` instead of `.find()` if you want to only get the child, add the `:first` selector, or use `.first()` after `.find()` or `.children()` to only get the first element.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.val()` to return the values and `.html()` to return the html.